# Continue reading XML after one attribute does not exists

Tags: java, android, xml, try-catch

I have this code for reading XML files:

```
try {

            File fXmlFile = new File(fullFilePath);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("task");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    int i = temp;

                    MyTasks.customers[i][11] = getTagValue("att1", eElement);
                    MyTasks.customers[i][12] = getTagValue("att8", eElement);
                    MyTasks.customers[i][13] = getTagValue("att2", eElement);
                    MyTasks.customers[i][14] = getTagValue("att7", eElement);
                    MyTasks.customers[i][15] = getTagValue("att3", eElement);
                    MyTasks.customers[i][16] = getTagValue("att4", eElement);
                    MyTasks.customers[i][18] = getTagValue("att5", eElement);
                    MyTasks.customers[i][19] = getTagValue("att6", eElement);
                    //ect
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            CreateLog.addToLog("[ReadXML]" + e.toString());

        }
```

Is it possible to continue reading the XML file after an error occurs. If one attribute does not exists the whole script stops reading and catchs an error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is that getTagValue method? Perhaps you should overload it with a method that takes an additional default value and instead of failing in case of missing attributes returns that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. Add a `try-catch` statement inside the `for-loop` and in case of catching an exception just use the `continue;` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Put `try-catch` inside the loop.

```
         for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
           try{
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                ...
            }
          }catch(Exception ex){...}
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
MyTasks.costumers[i][19] = callGetTagValue("x", eElement)


...

private callGetTagValue(String x, Object element){
try{
//foo
}catch(Exception e){
return "not found";
}
}
```

this way you won't loose the available data, which is the case when you just call continue;

Edit: For example you could also go this way:

```
try{
     for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    int i = temp;

                    MyTasks.customers[i][11] = getTagValue("att1", eElement);
                    MyTasks.customers[i][12] = getTagValue("att8", eElement);
                    MyTasks.customers[i][13] = getTagValue("att2", eElement);
                    MyTasks.customers[i][14] = getTagValue("att7", eElement);
                    MyTasks.customers[i][15] = getTagValue("att3", eElement);
                    MyTasks.customers[i][16] = getTagValue("att4", eElement);
                    MyTasks.customers[i][18] = getTagValue("att5", eElement);
                    MyTasks.customers[i][19] = getTagValue("att6", eElement);
                    //ect
                }}catch(Exception e){
continue;
}
```

but when the exception happens in

```
MyTasks.customers[i][13] = getTagValue("att2", eElement);
```

You won't receive the rest of the data